# Can I use a gMSA for stored credentials in a SSRS data source?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, managed-service-accounts

I have an instance of SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services service running under DOMAIN\reporting$ containing a data source that needs to query a database using the stored credential DOMAIN\database$. Unfortunately when I store the gMSA credential and click Test Connection I get `Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct.` It seems to work correctly if I use non-gMSA domain accounts. Is there any way I can use a gMSA as a stored credential in a SSRS data source?

Comment: Has the SSRS server been granted access to read the gMSA, and the gMSA installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, I already use the same gMSA for other services on the same server.

Comment: Is the actual source of data on a different server, or is it located on the same server? If the source data is on a different server, that other server will need to be granted permission to authenticate the gMSA as well.

Comment: Yes, both servers have access to the gMSA.